# Error 403 on SECOND postback of the same form (and various other situations)

Tags: asp.net, ssl, amazon-web-services, firewall, http-status-code-403

we recently migrated our application (IIS Server + DB Server) to AWS and also modified the network architecture a little bit.  The entry point of the system is an Astaro Firewall (we use the AWS AMI) which also host the SSL certificate of the web server.  Everything related to the firewall has been done by a vendor and we only have some read-only privileges.

We are getting 403 errors in a few situations but I will explain one, as they all may be related.

We got a form which query the database and return a report in HTML format (this report also have some checkbox to do updates).  The first time the form is submitted, we always get the report back.  If we wanna post the form again, updated with new data, it crash, returning **error 403**.  We noted that it doesn't crash when the first results returned a very low number of rows (or none).

Looking at the details of the POSTs in Developer Tools, what seems to be the only difference between a working and 403 error reply is the size of the data posted. The second post is **always bigger** because it contains the data of the first report (as the page have also other option to checkbox the rows).

Also, looking at the IIS logs we don't see any traces of the POST that crash.  **Nothing at all.**

This problem happen only in production.  In dev environment it's all working flawlessly.  The **only difference** is that the production have the firewall/ssl, while development is all open.  This is why we think it may be related to SSL.

The vendor is not the most helpful, we are looking for help to pinpoint the issue and trying to take the situation in our hands.

Any input appreciated.